# str.zfill() in pandas has problem with ' character

Tags: python, string, pandas

In connection with the question I asked here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375651/add-zeros-to-string-in-pandas-column-depends-of-length`
I have a problem with `str.zfill()` method.

My example data (column of DF):

```
0002131
dsda2123
eew12341
wewqsws1'
123
```

Following @jezrael advice I fill each row to 12 char by `str.zfill()` method.

Code:
 `df['SampleNumber'] = df['SampleNumber'].str.zfill(12)`

Result file:

```
000000002131
0000dsda2123
0000eew12341
wewqsws1'
000000000123
```

So all work fine but I have a problem with names where I have a `'` character. The method passes it, and in result series I got a unchanged name. What is the problem here? How can I deal with it? In the documentation of that method, I found nothing about a similar problem. And `type(wewqsws1')` it's `str`.

Can someone know how to fix it?

Expecting result:

```
000000002131
0000dsda2123
0000eew12341
000wewqsws1'
000000000123
```

Comment: for me its working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have empty space in the end try `str.strip().str.zfill(12)`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"SampleNumber": ['000000002131', '0000dsda2123', '0000eew12341', "wewqsws1'  ", '000000000123']})
df['SampleNumber'] = df['SampleNumber'].str.strip().str.zfill(12)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works. But weird is that in raw txt file I have `0000eew12341'` not `0000eew12341   '`. And in pandas dataframe too... so I don't know why it's working but it is. Thank U Rakesh